# Adding layout resources to androidTest

Tags: android, resources, android-resources, android-testing

I would like to add layout xml files into my `androidTest` folder to be used only for testing.

I added `res/layout` folder to `androidTest` and tried to add a layout file to it. But it gives error `URI is not registered` for `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Somehow the project does not recognize it as valid layout file.

Comment: Check this answer too, you have make a `import <yourDefaultPackage>.test.R:` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31492816/1797950

Answer (score 14):

It is tricky to add xml resources to `androidTest`.

Android Instrumentation tests create another APK to run the tests against your original application. Although you can access your `Context` and objects from your main application, you cannot modify the generated APK file of your app.

That means you cannot put additional layout xml to your original application from tests that are in the `androidTest` folder.

#### Solution:

Alternatively,

- you can create a `buildType` called `espresso`.
- Then, create an `espresso` folder where you can put any java or Android resource you want to add.

  - You can even modify your `AndroidManifest` there.
- Then, use `testBuildType 'espresso'`

Your `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
android {
  testBuildType 'espresso'

  buildTypes {
    espresso.initWith(buildTypes.release)
  }
}

dependencies {
  espressoCompile 'somedependency' // you can even have special dependencies
}
```

When you run your espresso tests around that flavor, you will have an access to additional layout xml files you added.

Should look like this:

[image]

Comment: great answer @tasomaniac. It would be better to use a testBuildType that is not debug, so you can avoid to inflate your set of flavors.

Answer (score 14):

That's easy! In general, you should just put your resources under the `src/androidTest/res` folder. And that is! Then you can use it in your `src/androidTest/java` files. Yes, you can't use *test* layouts in your production APK, but **you can use your test layouts in your test APK**.

There're some problems that might confuse you. For instance autocompletion works well not so very often, but, anyway, it builds and works.

Recently I wrote [custom control for masked EditText](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask) so I don't want to put any activity into the library, but I do want to have an activity to check the view and I do want inflate it from XML. You can see the whole code on the github page, here're some key moments:

```
$ tree androidTest/
androidTest/
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── java
│   └── ru
│       └── egslava
│           └── lib_phone
│               ├── MainActivityTest.java
│               ├── TestActivity.java
│               └── actions
│                   ├── HintViewAction.java
│                   ├── KeepHintViewAction.java
│                   └── SetTextViewAction.java
└── res
    ├── layout
    │   └── activity_main.xml
    └── values
        └── styles.xml
```

So you can see, that under androidTest there's some kind of a separate project with its own manifest that registers Activity and so on :-) I would share more files, but it's just a project, no more and you always can look up the link.

The only thing that I'd like to warn you, that you should be ready that Android Studio will show you that your project contains errors even if that's not true :-) Good luck!

[image: Be ready that AndroidStudio will show you that your project contains error even if that's not true]

Comment: One note: you have to use `{module_package}.test.R` class to access resources in `androidTest/res` folder.

Comment: I'm using view binding in my project, and when I do this it doesn't generate view bindings for the layout and so I can't compile my project (get "unresolved reference" errors). any idea how to get it to build view binding layouts for such classes?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment, but wanted to further add to @Slava's answer. If someone can add it as a comment, by all means.

Try suppressing the lint errors with the accepted answer from this question.
[Android Studio Remove lint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455291/android-studio-remove-lint-error)